# Is it possible to create a full screen PopupWindow and make it not cancelable?

Tags: android, popupwindow

I'm trying to create a full screen `PopupWindow` and avoid the back button from dismissing it but from what I've been seeing it looks like the two are mutually exclusive. I've created the `PopupWindow` using `LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT` for both `width` and `height`. I also set it to focusable, and set a null background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PopupWindow is not good for a window.you can try  using DialogFragment!Google recommended it,and it is very easy to make kinds of windows with lifecycle.

Comment: Thanks, I had this suspicion but was hoping I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you can use an activity with you desired animation and override the `onBackPressed()` method

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

}
```

Comment: Doesn't work, the window gets the back event regardless.